# When I click on the wifi icon at the bottom of the screen nothing happens

Tags: windows-10

After connecting my school computer to WiFi at a resort I can no longer connect to my home WiFi and get online.

When I click on the wifi icon at the bottom of the screen nothing happens. I have a program called "who is on my wifi" and on start up it now say " your computer computers blocking hardware did not initialize correctly " but I don't have no program doing that.i have windows 10, I had to YouTube my settings because network discovery was off and wouldn't stay on,I fix that but still can't get on any connections.

Comment: Is this a computer owned by your college or school? Or is it a computer you yourself purchased for school use? Also, what is this "Who is on my Wifi" program and why did you decide it was the correct software to try to diagnose or resolve this issue?

Comment: I have noticed this happening a lot with all my windows 10 devices

Comment: Finally, what settings did you change to enable Network Discovery, and what directed you to change those settings?

Comment: Just FYI, Network Discovery is not the same thing as scanning for WiFi networks. Typically speaking, you don't need Network Discovery turned on unless you are trying to use resources that are on other computers on a network.

Comment: Ok for the quick info,now can u point me to the right info to have my wifi and internet back on my laptop? Never encountered a problem like this.under my network connections my wifi have a red x,when I right click on it to connect it does nothing.

Comment: This is my computer, I had use it for school but graduated, I google problems like this and they gave a couple of info on on how to solve it. Every since I came back from that resort,my settings is all mess up

Answer (score 1):

Hi left click the taskbar and click on task manager click on more details then find the windows explorer and restart it